# Homebrew warnings: Ignoring X because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine X --version Y

Tags: ruby, rubygems, homebrew

Whenever I run a homebrew command I get these warnings, which I'd like to fix:

```
Ignoring RedCloth-4.2.9 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine RedCloth --version 4.2.9
Ignoring commonmarker-0.17.9 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine commonmarker --version 0.17.9
Ignoring RedCloth-4.2.9 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine RedCloth --version 4.2.9
Ignoring commonmarker-0.17.9 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine commonmarker --version 0.17.9
```

Running `gem pristine RedCloth --version 4.2.9` gives the following:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Failed to find gems ["RedCloth"] = 4.2.9
```

I investigated `gem`:

- `which gem` > `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem`
- `which ruby` > `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby`
- `gem environment`:

  ```
  RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.5 (2019-10-01 patchlevel 114) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/victor/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/victor/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
   - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
   - /Users/victor/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
   - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
   - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
   - /Users/victor/.pyenv/shims
   - /opt/local/bin
   - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
   - /Users/victor/.pyenv
   - /usr/local/bin
   - /usr/bin
   - /bin
   - /usr/sbin
   - /sbin
   - /Library/TeX/texbin
   - /bin
   - /Users/victor/bin
   - /usr/local/bin
   - /Users/victor/.local/bin
  ```
- `gem list`:

  ```
  *** LOCAL GEMS ***

  activesupport (5.2.4, 4.2.10)
  addressable (2.7.0, 2.5.2)
  bundle (0.0.1)
  bundler (2.0.2)
  coffee-script (2.4.1)
  coffee-script-source (1.11.1)
  colorator (1.1.0)
  commonmarker (0.17.13)
  concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
  did_you_mean (1.3.0)
  dnsruby (1.61.3, 1.61.2)
  em-websocket (0.5.1)
  ethon (0.12.0)
  eventmachine (1.2.7)
  execjs (2.7.0)
  extras (0.3.0)
  faraday (0.17.1, 0.15.4)
  fastimage (2.1.7, 2.1.5)
  ffi (1.11.3, 1.10.0)
  forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
  gemoji (3.0.1, 3.0.0)
  github-pages (203, 193)
  github-pages-health-check (1.16.1, 1.8.1)
  html-pipeline (2.12.2, 2.10.0)
  http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
  i18n (0.9.5)
  jekyll (3.8.5, 3.7.4)
  jekyll-assets (3.0.12, 2.4.0)
  jekyll-avatar (0.7.0, 0.6.0)
  jekyll-coffeescript (1.1.1)
  jekyll-commonmark (1.3.1, 1.2.0)
  jekyll-commonmark-ghpages (0.1.6, 0.1.5)
  jekyll-default-layout (0.1.4)
  jekyll-feed (0.13.0, 0.11.0)
  jekyll-gist (1.5.0)
  jekyll-github-metadata (2.12.1, 2.9.4)
  jekyll-mentions (1.5.1, 1.4.1)
  jekyll-optional-front-matter (0.3.2, 0.3.0)
  jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
  jekyll-readme-index (0.3.0, 0.2.0)
  jekyll-redirect-from (0.15.0, 0.14.0)
  jekyll-relative-links (0.6.1, 0.5.3)
  jekyll-remote-theme (0.4.1, 0.3.1)
  jekyll-sanity (1.2.0)
  jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.2)
  jekyll-seo-tag (2.6.1, 2.5.0)
  jekyll-sitemap (1.4.0, 1.2.0)
  jekyll-swiss (1.0.0, 0.4.0)
  jekyll-theme-architect (0.1.1)
  jekyll-theme-cayman (0.1.1)
  jekyll-theme-dinky (0.1.1)
  jekyll-theme-hacker (0.1.1)
  jekyll-theme-leap-day (0.1.1)
  jekyll-theme-merlot (0.1.1)
  jekyll-theme-midnight (0.1.1)
  jekyll-theme-minimal (0.1.1)
  jekyll-theme-modernist (0.1.1)
  jekyll-theme-primer (0.5.4, 0.5.3)
  jekyll-theme-slate (0.1.1)
  jekyll-theme-tactile (0.1.1)
  jekyll-theme-time-machine (0.1.1)
  jekyll-titles-from-headings (0.5.3, 0.5.1)
  jekyll-watch (2.2.1, 2.1.2)
  jemoji (0.11.1, 0.10.1)
  kramdown (1.17.0)
  liquid (4.0.3, 4.0.0)
  liquid-tag-parser (1.9.0)
  listen (3.2.1, 3.1.5)
  maruku (0.7.3)
  mercenary (0.3.6)
  mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
  minima (2.5.1, 2.5.0)
  minitest (5.13.0, 5.11.3)
  multipart-post (2.1.1, 2.0.0)
  net-telnet (0.2.0)
  nokogiri (1.10.7, 1.10.1)
  octokit (4.14.0, 4.13.0)
  pathutil (0.16.2)
  power_assert (1.1.3)
  public_suffix (3.1.1, 2.0.5)
  rack (2.0.7, 1.6.11)
  rake (13.0.1, 12.3.3, 12.3.2)
  rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
  rb-inotify (0.10.0)
  rouge (3.13.0, 2.2.1)
  ruby-enum (0.7.2)
  ruby_dep (1.5.0)
  rubyzip (2.0.0, 1.2.2)
  safe_yaml (1.0.5, 1.0.4)
  sass (3.7.4, 3.7.3)
  sass-listen (4.0.0)
  sawyer (0.8.2, 0.8.1)
  sprockets (4.0.0, 3.7.2)
  terminal-table (1.8.0)
  test-unit (3.2.9)
  thread_safe (0.3.6)
  typhoeus (1.3.1)
  tzinfo (1.2.5)
  uglifier (3.2.0)
  unicode-display_width (1.6.0, 1.4.1)
  xmlrpc (0.3.0)
  ```

But not sure what to do next. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: ` I get these warnings, which I'd like to fix` => basically it seems like something's wrong with my ruby setup and I don't know much about ruby so I don't know how to go further from here

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `gem pristine X --version Y` is not working may because your system gem is not your Homebrew gem...

First, run `brew config` and check your **Homebrew Ruby** path. It may like this:

```sh
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/bin/ruby
```

Then replace ruby with gem, run pristine command:

```sh
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/bin/gem pristine X --version Y
```